# How to launch a tutorial on first app launch using SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to launch a tutorial when my SwiftUI app first launches. Where in the project should this code go and how do I launch the tutorial, which is just a SwiftUI View, when the app first launches?

I already know how to check if the app has launched before using UserDefaults. I am wanting to know how to launch the SwiftUI view and then how to launch the standard ContentView after the user completes the tutorial.

```swift
let hasLaunchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasLaunchedBefore")

if hasLaunchedBefore {
     // Not first launch
     // Load ContentView here
} else {
     // Is first launch
     // Load tutorial SwiftUI view here
     UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasLaunchedBefore") // Set hasLaunchedBefore key to true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put this in your sceneDelegate

```
let hasLaunchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasLaunchedBefore")
let content = ContentView()
let tutorial = TutorialView()
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
      let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
       if hasLaunchedBefore {
           window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
       } else {
           window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: tutorial)
           UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasLaunchedBefore") 
       }
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: That works when it is the first launch, but if I close the app after that and reopen it, it crashes.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to add one of my Environment Objects back to the content view. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In your `SampleApp` which after SwiftUI 2.0:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SampleApp: App {
  @AppStorage("didLaunchBefore") var didLaunchBefore: Bool = true
  let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      if didLaunchBefore {
        SplashView()
      } else {
        ContentView()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then add a button with action like below in `SplashView`:

```swift
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "didLaunchBefore")
```